# Managing transactions, spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions

In my spring boot application , i want to avoid booking more than one appointment per date but when two requests of booking for a date x are done in the same time i have the two appointments saved in the database with the same date x.
How to resolve this, any help please?

Comment: The answer is in your question - use a transaction. If the question is "what is a database transaction and how do I use one in Spring" I would say that that is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

1. If possible do not insert the second booking (e.g. check with a query before inserting or lock the booking pessimistic). This should be the best way - there are several ways to prevent concurrent bookings. You will also find a lot of discussions on stackoverflow.
2. If this is not possible in your use case: Use a database constraint (this will throw an exception if booking and date is already in your database and you can handle the error in our application) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570810/5978781