# Create trigger to check if a record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a trigger to check if a record exist before insert, if it exists rollback, if not continue to do the insert.
The thing is when I do the insert it always rollback.
what should I do?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CHECKCONSOMMATION]
ON [dbo].[ConsommationEau]
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @IDABONNEMENT INT
DECLARE @DEFMONTH DATETIME

SELECT @IDABONNEMENT = inserted.idAbonnement FROM inserted
SELECT @DEFMONTH = inserted.Periode FROM inserted


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ConsommationEau WHERE idAbonnement = @IDABONNEMENT AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, Periode, @DEFMONTH) = 0)
    BEGIN
    RAISERROR('THIS RECORD IS ALREADY EXISTS', 10, 1)
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
    END
```

and this my table.

```
     USE [GESTEAU]
      GO

 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ConsommationEau]    Script Date: 4/20/2017  
 :08:53 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsommationEau](
[idConsomationEau] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Periode] [date] NULL,
[Qte] [int] NULL,
[idAbonnement] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ConsommationEau]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN 
KEY([idAbonnement])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AbonnementEau] ([idAbonnement])
 GO
```

Comment: Can you clarify the exact requirement? It looks like you're trying to limit the table to only one row, per `idAbonnement`, per month. Is that correct? (By the way, your current trigger is badly broken - `inserted` can contain multiple rows. You've no guarantee, in such cases, the `@IDABONNEMENT` and `@DEFMONTH` even come from the same row, let alone correctly deal with those multiple rows)

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to limit the table to only one row, per idAbonnement, per month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the intention is that the table can only contain one row, per `idAbonnement`, per month, then I wouldn't use a trigger. I'd use a persisted computed column and a unique index:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConsommationEau](
[idConsomationEau] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Periode] [date] NULL,
[Qte] [int] NULL,
[idAbonnement] [int] NULL,
PeriodeMonth as DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,Periode),0) persisted
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
create unique index IX_ConsommationEau_Monthly
    on ConsommationEau (idAbonnement, PeriodeMonth)
```

This way you've *declared* what should be unique rather than having to write *procedural* code, and you've avoided the problem with your current trigger where it doesn't currently deal correctly with multi-row inserts.

(The `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair in the computed column definition just ensures that any date within a month gets converted to the 1st of that same month, and is my generally preferred means of adjusting date(time) values)

---

To do this inside a trigger, you have to realise that a `FOR INSERT` trigger is also known as an `AFTER` trigger. You'll always find a row that matches the just inserted row(s) since *by the time the trigger fires, they've already been added to the table* - the rows are matching themselves.

Normally, if you want to prevent rows being inserted, I'd recommend that you use an `INSTEAD` of trigger to prevent them ever appearing in the final table. However, that can become awkward - especially because it's easy to forget that the two conflicting rows might not be a newly inserted one and an existing one, but instead two newly inserted rows.

So, we'll stick with the `FOR INSERT` trigger. All we need is something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CHECKCONSOMMATION]
ON [dbo].[ConsommationEau]
FOR INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS(
         SELECT * FROM ConsommationEau WHERE
            idAbonnement IN (SELECT idAbonnement FROM inserted)
         GROUP BY idAbonnement,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,Periode),0)
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('THIS RECORD IS ALREADY EXISTS', 10, 1)
      ROLLBACK
    END
```

(But note that this has now been transformed into a simple uniqueness test within the table, which as you'll observe, is more neatly enforced using the constructs designed for that, as used in my first solution above)

Comment: I have no choice here, I've told to use the trigger, It's been week now looking for a proper answer.

Comment: @hyungsik - I've done a trigger version, but I'd really not recommend it. You're effectively implementing a `UNIQUE` constraint by hand rather than letting the system use built in mechanisms - I don't see the value in that.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're right. in a development environment I would definitely avoid using it, but now since I've told to only use trigger, I'll stick with your answer.

Comment: No need to use an index, a simple unique constraint would be enough on the computed column, index maintenance costs on updates/inserts and may alter performances.

Comment: @Hybris95 - a `unique` constraint is always *enforced* by an index being created (at least in SQL Server). You cannot avoid the index. So far as I'm aware, there's no *additional* cost in declaring it as a `unique constraint` but that's the only direction in which a difference could occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keywords BEGIN and END after your IF to make sure the ROLLBACK takes the IF in count.

```
IF EXISTS [condition]
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Error',10,1)
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END
```

But mostly, I would suggest you using a **check constraint** in the table definition :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570810/3635715

Microsoft Reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql

Comment: Yes, I did before posting the question, yet I didn't work.

Comment: Watch my edit about constraint definitions which to me would apply to what you are trying to achieve (using a trigger is a bit "dirty")

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an INSTEAD OF trigger to only insert if it is not matched:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CHECKCONSOMMATION]
ON [dbo].[ConsommationEau]
Instead of INSERT
AS
    MERGE ConsommationEau c
    USING inserted i
    on c.idAbonnement = i.idAbonnement AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, c.Periode, i.Periode) = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([idConsomationEau, [Periode], [Qte], [idAbonnement]) 
        VALUES (i.[idConsomationEau, i.[Periode], i.[Qte], i.[idAbonnement])
```

Comment: The issue with trying to do this as an `instead of` (assuming you correct the `on` to the required conditions, which also requires `Periode` to be taken into consideration) is that `inserted`, *itself*, may contain two conflicting rows.

Comment: Merge is not a good technique in any event. Ii is very hard to troubleshoot when you have a data issue. It has also had some bug problems.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have fixed the ON conditions. If there are conflicting rows in the insert it poses the problem of which row should be inserted - a logical problem.